# Content not being displayed in the correct language

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I am trying to make this decision on what content (Messages) to be displayed based on the useragent. Everything works correctly when I user query param, or a meta tag. it also works correctly in Firefox. In firefox I change the language from english to french, reload the page and everything comes up correctly. This is baed on the useragent. If I load the page in chrome/IE I get the default (English) only. If I set my system language to French (my other language) everything seems to work as well. Any ideas why setting the language in chrome and IE have no affect no the content?  I verified the headers and the requests are being made for French content? What am I missing?

My gwt.xml file is based on the one I found here http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.3/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/I18N.gwt.xml

It was my understanding that all I needed to add was the following to my gwt.xml
set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent" value="Y"

Also I found the following [Why does GWT ignore browser locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156412/why-does-gwt-ignore-browser-locale) which seems to indicate it won't work in IE but what about chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4228

TL;DR: there's no reliable way of getting the info you're looking at in JavaScript, the `navigator` object gives you the locale of the browser (i.e. the one used for the browser's own menus et al.), not the user's language preferences (except in Firefox).
Your best bet is to use a dynamic host page and generate the appropriate `<meta>` on the server depending on the request headers (i.e. content negotiation).