# GWT dynamic localization without appending parameters in URL

Tags: gwt, internationalization

As per the GWT docs, there are two ways two internationalize my GWT app. One is, declare the language in the HTML itself (hardcoding) through `meta` tags, another is to use a query param in the URL (like `&locale=de`).

My webapp is dynamic,different users from different locales will be using it, so the first option is not viable. The 2nd option is fine, but somehow, appending query params to a URL is my pet peeve. I tried to make it dynamic by doing something like `$("head).append("<meta name='gwt:property' content='locale=de'>");` first thing on `onModuleLoad`, it doesn't work.

My app will actually be a redirection, some other web-page will contain a redirection like `foo.com&locale=de`. Based on that, it will load the required locale fine. But after that, I want to reload it again without showing the query param in the URL, taking the locale information from cookies which can be set in the first load. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: The client's browser should tell the app which locale it's using. It your GWT project isn't set up for that locale it will just use the default locale.

You don't need to set any locales in production, only in dev mode so that you can ensure that the locales that you set are working properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156412/why-does-gwt-ignore-browser-locale

Answer (score 3):

Adding the parameter to a model (in a `Controller`) and picking it up on the client (in a `*.jsp`) will work for you?

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=${locale}">
```

Then you just need to refresh the page and reset the locale value in a controller. Add the meta-tag code in your `html/jsp` page, it should be there prior to page loading.

`onModuleLoad` works with code already loaded to the browser window, so appending `meta` after loading will not work.

Answer (score 3):

### There is a third option using `cookie`.

Reference - [GWT Internationalization for dynamically generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256782/gwt-internationalization-for-dynamically-generated-content/)

Ensure you set locale value to the cookie or have a default value for your cookie before user chooses his locale. In our case user chooses a language before login ( where i set the cookie locale value for the user) and read this into the gwt application on load.